# How do I get the value of captured shader parameters

Tags: c++, c, directx, shader, direct3d

I'm looking for a frame capture program (like Intel GPA, GPUPerfStudio, PerfHUD, or DX Debugger) that allows me to get the value of shader parameters when I debug a captured frame. In Intel GPA, it shows me the name as well as the type (like `float`, `float2`, `float3`, or `float4`) of the parameters, but it doesn't show me their value.

I tried looking at the API log, but it is unclear, and instead of printing the value parameter of `SETVERTEXSHADERCONSTANTF` (which I presume sets the value of a shader parameter) it prints `System.Single[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS2013 you can debug your hlsl code with it: [Debugging HLSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873197.aspx). See also [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/GoingNative-27-Improvements-to-Visual-Studio-Graphics-Diagnostics)